# How do I search divs for text from a select form and change diplay of the divs to none?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to hide divs based on a value in a dropdown selector. It only changes the first div instead of the ones that do not contain the selected value. I'm not sure where I have went wrong. Here is my code.

```js
document.getElementById("SearchFilter").onchange = function() {
  var matcher = new RegExp(document.getElementById("SearchFilter").value, "gi");
  for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("v-product").length; i++) {
    if (matcher.test(document.getElementsByClassName("tipue_search_content_text")[i].innerHTML)) {
      document.getElementById("v-product").style.display = "inline-block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("v-product").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="SearchFilter">
    <option value="">Choose Part Type</option>
    <option value="belt">Belt</option>
    <option value="filter">Filter</option>
    <option value="blade">Blade</option>
  </select>
</form>

<div class="v-product-grid" id="tipue_search_content">
  <div class="v-product" id="v-product">
    <div class="tipue_search_content_title">
      <a href="/John-Deere-V-Belt-M110367-p/M110367.htm">
        <div class="BrandTitle">
          John Deere
        </div>V-Belt M110367</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tipue_search_content_text">
      <a href="/John-Deere-V-Belt-M110367-p/M110367.htm">
        <object class="v-product__img" data="/v/vspfiles/photos/M110367-1.jpg" type="image/png">
        </object>
        <div class="PriceText">
          <b>Price: $33.23</b>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=M110367">
        <button class="btn srchbtn AddToCartBtn" type="button">ADD TO CART
          <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
        </button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="v-product" id="v-product">
  <div class="tipue_search_content_title">
    <a href="/John-Deere-Inline%20Fuel%20Filter%20AM116304-p/AM116304.htm">
      <div class="BrandTitle">
        John Deere
      </div>Inline Fuel Filter AM116304</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tipue_search_content_text">
    <a href="/John-Deere-Inline-Fuel-Filter-AM116304-p/AM116304.htm">
      <object class="v-product__img" data="/v/vspfiles/photos/AM116304-1.jpg" type="image/png">
      </object>
      <div class="PriceText">
        <b>Price: $4.55</b>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=AM116304">
      <button class="btn srchbtn AddToCartBtn" type="button">ADD TO CART
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
      </button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="v-product" id="v-product">
  <div class="tipue_search_content_title">
    <a href="/John-Deere-Blade-M119206-Set-of-3-Blades-p/M119206.htm">
      <div class="BrandTitle">
        John Deere
      </div>Blade M119206 - Set of 3 Blades</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tipue_search_content_text">
    <a href="/John-Deere-Blade-M119206-Set-of-3-Blades-p/M119206.htm">
      <object class="v-product__img" data="/v/vspfiles/photos/M119206-1.jpg" type="image/png">
      </object>
      <div class="PriceText">
        <b>Price: $76.4</b>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=&amp;M119206">
      <button class="btn srchbtn AddToCartBtn" type="button">ADD TO CART
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
      </button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't stated what the problem is, or given a sample of your HTML, which would help a lot. That said you should probably set the `display` property on the element within the iteration using it's index: `document.getElementById("v-product")[i].style.display = ...`

Comment: sorry, i updated my post. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for updating. You need to fix your HTML as its invalid - you can't have buttons or block level elements within `a` tags

Comment: i changed getElementById to getElementsByClassName and added set the display using its index and that solved the problem. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

why so complicated? .. just use jQuery
this will hide every DIV with the content selected in `mySelectedInput`

```
$('#SearchFilter').on('change', function() {
    allDivs = $('.v-product');       

    $.each(allDivs, function() {
       if($(this).html() == mySelectedInput) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The display needed to be set using its index and by class name.

```js
document.getElementById("SearchFilter").onchange = function() {
  var matcher = new RegExp(document.getElementById("SearchFilter").value, "gi");
  for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("v-product").length; i++) {
    if (matcher.test(document.getElementsByClassName("tipue_search_content_text")[i].innerHTML)) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("v-product")[i].style.display = "inline-block";
    } else {
      document.getElementsByClassName("v-product")[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="SearchFilter">
    <option value="">Choose Part Type</option>
    <option value="belt">Belt</option>
    <option value="filter">Filter</option>
    <option value="blade">Blade</option>
  </select>
</form>

<div class="v-product-grid" id="tipue_search_content">
  <div class="v-product" id="v-product">
    <div class="tipue_search_content_title">
      <a href="/John-Deere-V-Belt-M110367-p/M110367.htm">
        <div class="BrandTitle">
          John Deere
        </div>V-Belt M110367</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tipue_search_content_text">
      <a href="/John-Deere-V-Belt-M110367-p/M110367.htm">
        <object class="v-product__img" data="/v/vspfiles/photos/M110367-1.jpg" type="image/png">
        </object>
        <div class="PriceText">
          <b>Price: $33.23</b>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=M110367">
        <button class="btn srchbtn AddToCartBtn" type="button">ADD TO CART
          <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
        </button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="v-product" id="v-product">
  <div class="tipue_search_content_title">
    <a href="/John-Deere-Inline%20Fuel%20Filter%20AM116304-p/AM116304.htm">
      <div class="BrandTitle">
        John Deere
      </div>Inline Fuel Filter AM116304</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tipue_search_content_text">
    <a href="/John-Deere-Inline-Fuel-Filter-AM116304-p/AM116304.htm">
      <object class="v-product__img" data="/v/vspfiles/photos/AM116304-1.jpg" type="image/png">
      </object>
      <div class="PriceText">
        <b>Price: $4.55</b>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=AM116304">
      <button class="btn srchbtn AddToCartBtn" type="button">ADD TO CART
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
      </button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="v-product" id="v-product">
  <div class="tipue_search_content_title">
    <a href="/John-Deere-Blade-M119206-Set-of-3-Blades-p/M119206.htm">
      <div class="BrandTitle">
        John Deere
      </div>Blade M119206 - Set of 3 Blades</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tipue_search_content_text">
    <a href="/John-Deere-Blade-M119206-Set-of-3-Blades-p/M119206.htm">
      <object class="v-product__img" data="/v/vspfiles/photos/M119206-1.jpg" type="image/png">
      </object>
      <div class="PriceText">
        <b>Price: $76.4</b>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=&amp;M119206">
      <button class="btn srchbtn AddToCartBtn" type="button">ADD TO CART
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
      </button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```